# formidable toggle switch, how to click the label?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, toggle, formidable

Currently, the below HTML code only switches when you click the input (ie. the center switch).
I need the switch to happen when you click the labels (ie. Yes or No).
How to make that happen?

```
        <div>
            <span class="frm_off_label frm_switch_opt">No</span>
            <label class="frm_switch">
                   <input type="checkbox" name="2002" id="field_2002" value="Yes" checked="checked" 
                            data-off="No" data-sectionid="2002" data-frmval="Yes" placeholder="Yes">
                  <span class="frm_slider"></span>
              </label>
               <span class="frm_on_label frm_switch_opt">Yes</span>
         </div>
```

What are the ways to make the click of Yes or No, do the same thing as clicking the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting the checked status of input -

HTML

> ```
>    <div>
>         <span class="frm_off_label frm_switch_opt">No</span>
>         <label class="frm_switch">
>                <input type="checkbox" name="2002" id="field_2002" value="Yes" checked="checked" 
>                         data-off="No" data-sectionid="2002" data-frmval="Yes" placeholder="Yes">
>               <span class="frm_slider"></span>
>           </label>
>            <span class="frm_on_label frm_switch_opt">Yes</span>
>      </div>
> ```

JS (with jquery)

```
$('.frm_off_label').on('click', function(){
        $(this).next('label').find("input")[0].checked = false;
});


$('.frm_on_label').on('click', function(){
        $(this).prev('label').find("input")[0].checked = true;
});
```

CSS (optioanl)

```
.frm_switch_opt{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

You can see it in action on jsfiddle

```
https://jsfiddle.net/guruling/tegmps9b/27/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `label` combine with [`for="element_id"`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_label_for.asp) like `for="field_2002"` attribute to achieve it.

> The for attribute specifies which form element a label is bound to.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <label for="field_2002" class="frm_off_label frm_switch_opt">No</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="2002" id="field_2002" value="Yes" checked="checked" 
                    data-off="No" data-sectionid="2002" data-frmval="Yes" placeholder="Yes">
    <label for="field_2002" class="frm_on_label frm_switch_opt">Yes</label>               
</div>
```